# Sum over a collection of agents

Tags: java, anylogic

So I'm trying to sum over each index of a group of agents and display the total in a Time Plot.

My current solution looks like this:
[Descriptive Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNY18.png)

Obviously it looks clunky, and i shouldn't have to explicitly sum over all 12 indexes.

How can I sum up the agents more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sum( steelMills, s->s.Inventory )
```

Comment: The more 'AnyLogic-native' solution is to use population statistics, not explicit (and opaque) Java 8 lambda expressions.

Comment: I find java expressions for such a case more convenient and faster. But anyway, it's the same result.